# I want to create a folder that what I put in the name textbox is the name of the created folder

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
    
    Dim msgValue As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim startPath As String
    Dim myName1 As String
    
    msgValue = MsgBox("Do you want to save the data?", vbYesNo + vbInformation, "Confirmation")
    
    If msgValue = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    
    Call Submit
    Call Reset
    
    


    startPath = "C:\Users\earld\Desktop\Therapy\Record\"
    myName1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Text


    Dim folderPathWithName As String
    folderPathWithName = startPath & Application.PathSeparator & myName1 & " " & frmForm.txtName.Value & Format$(Date, " dd-mm-yyyy")
    If Dir(folderPathWithName, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
        MkDir folderPathWithName
    Else
       MsgBox "Folder already exists"
       Exit Sub
    End If

    
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: It works but it only creates dates. I hope someone can help me here i need names and dates

Comment: It is difficult to say what exactly happens after calling the `Reset` procedure. I dare to assume that the code for this procedure clears cell A1 on the active sheet - therefore `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Text` returns an empty string. It is possible that the assignment to the variable `myName1` should be moved above, immediately after calling `Submit`

Comment: `Application.PathSeparator` is doubled. Delete one instance of it.

Comment: `myName1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Text` might not be looking at the correct sheet.  Try changin `ActiveSheet` to something like `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` so it always looks at Sheet1 in the file that contains the code.  Also as @MGonet said - you have `"C:\Users\earld\Desktop\Therapy\Record\"` with a path separator at the end, you then use `startPath & Application.PathSeparator & myName1` which adds a second path separator in.

Comment: i think my problem is this folderPathWithName = startPath & Application.PathSeparator & myName1 & " " & frmForm.txtName.Value & Format$(Date, " dd-mm-yyyy")

Answer (score 0):

The code is working for me, I created a form, with the same names, and an object of that form.  The parts I can not see are the Submit and Reset Functions.  Assuming the issue is how the form or the functions handles the text, I would suggest casting the text with CStr to ensure it is correctly formatted. If you run debug, you should be able to identify where the string changes.

Original:

```
folderPathWithName = startPath & Application.PathSeparator & myName1 & " " & frmForm.txtName.Value & Format$(Date, " dd-mm-yyyy")
```

To fix, you need to cast to a CStr when assign the value.

```
folderPathWithName = startPath & Application.PathSeparator & myName1 & " " & CStr(frmForm.txtName.Value) & Format$(Date, " dd-mm-yyyy")
```